# Adding a decimal point to an integer with awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

So, I have csv files to use with hledger, and last field of every row is the amount for that line transaction.

Lines are in the following format:
date1, date2, description, amount

With the amount format any length between 4 and 6 digits; now for some reason all amounts are missing the period before the last two digits.

**Now**: 1000
**Should be**: 10.00

**Now**: 25452
**Should be**: 254.52

How to add a '.' before the last two digits of all lines, preferably with sed/awk?

So the input file is:

```
16.12.2005,18.12.2005,ATM,2000
17.12.2005,18.12.2005,utility,12523
18.12.2005,20.12.2005,salary,459023
```

desired output

```
16.12.2005,18.12.2005,ATM,20.00
17.12.2005,18.12.2005,utility,125.23
18.12.2005,20.12.2005,salary,4590.23
```

Thanks

Comment: Show what the file looks like

Comment: Instead of describing your input and output with words, please give a sample.

Comment: The title and the question differ: in the title you ask for a thousand separator, but in the body of the question, you ask for a decimal point. I have taken the freedom to edit your misleading title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
awk -F , '{printf "%s,%s,%s,%-6.2f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4/100.0}'
```

You should always add a sample of your input file and of the output you want in your question.

In this input you provide, you will have to define what has to happen when the description field contains a `,`, or if it is possible to have amount of less than 100 as input.

In function of your answer, I will need to adapt the code or not.

Comment: Put the input and output files into your question, as preformatted code.

Comment: It is very kind of you to accept my solution, but I prefer honestly that of Ed Morton with `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/..$/.&/'
```

......................

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **cut utility** to get the desired output. In your case, you always want to add '.' before the last two digits. So essentially it can be thought as something like this:

**Step 1:** Get all the characters from the beginning till the last 2 characters.

**Step 2:** Get the last 2 characters from the end.

**Step 3:** Concatenate them with the character that you want ('.' in this case).

The corresponding command for each of the step is the following:

```
$ a='17.12.2005,18.12.2005,utility,12523'
$ b=`echo $a | rev | cut -c3- | rev` 
$ c=`echo $a | rev | cut -c1-2 | rev` 
$ echo $b"."$c
```

This would produce the output

```
17.12.2005,18.12.2005,utility,125.23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
16.12.2005,18.12.2005,ATM,20.00 
17.12.2005,18.12.2005,utility,125.23 
18.12.2005,20.12.2005,salary,4590.23

awk -F, '{sub(/..$/,".& ")}1' file
```